# Can you always find $\alpha$ such that $\int_{a}^{b} (f(x) - \alpha g(x))^n \,dx < \int_{a}^{b} f(x)^n \,dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, integral-inequality

$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are functions $\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$.
Both functions are non-zero between $x \in [a, b]$ apart from at most a finite number of points.

Is it always possible to find $\alpha$ such that $$\int_{a}^{b} (f(x) - \alpha g(x))^n \,dx < \int_{a}^{b} f(x)^n \,dx$$?

$$\alpha \in \mathbb{R} , \quad n \in \mathbb Z \setminus \{0\}$$

If the answer is not "yes" what about case of $n = 2$?

Edit: the question originally used $\mathbb{C}$ in place of now $\mathbb{R}$.
Also integrals are Riemann integrals.

Comment: What does $<$ mean in $\mathbb C$? Are $a,b\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: It’s been a while since I studied complex analysis. But Are you sure $f$ and $g$ are necessarily integrable? Also, don’t you have to be more specific as to what kind of integration you’re doing? Like, is it a contour integral or generalised Riemann Integral?

Comment: Does this even make sense in the complex numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A standard example.
On $[0,1]$, let $f(x) = \cos(2\pi x)$ and $g(x) = \sin(2\pi x)$.
Take $n=2$.  Then for all $\alpha$ we have
$$
\int_0^1\big|f(x)-\alpha g(x)\big|^2\;dx \ge \int_0^1 |f(x)|^2\;dx
$$
I used absolute values in there to allow for $\alpha$ to be complex.
This is because $f$ and $g$ are orthogonal in $L^2$.

Comment: Great, thank you. Perhaps I need to create another question but what would be the answer to the original question if we required f and g be not orthogonal?